# I possibly broke windows defender windows 10

Tags: windows-10

I did so many things to this computer that I dont even rember so there is a large possibility that I am the one to blame on this.This morning when I turned on my pc Windows notified me that the computer is unprotected so I went straight to control panel -> sistema and security -> security and maintenance but the actívate now button on Windows defender is unclicable- it sits there in grayscale.In services.msc Windows defender is missing.In gpedit.msc -> Windows components Windows defender is missing.Can I restore it somehow ?

Comment: Georgi - while someone here may give you an answer, this really isn't the right site. I've started the process to have the question migrated.

Comment: NP. It's already done. GL with your computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn on Windows Defender real-time protection in Windows 10 by selecting the Start button [image], and then selecting *Settings* -> *Update & security* -> *Windows Defender*.

[image]

Comment: real-time protection is on and unchangaeble, on the top it sais your organization administrates some of the configuration options.Does that mean its on because I still get notificactions that there is a problem with the antivirus protection...that particular window i never saw.

Comment: Check if possible that whatever window you are referring to is put there by Windows 10 and is not some bogus window that was put there by a scammer. Malware is getting stealthier and nastier all the time, including malware that claims to be your operating system's antivirus program..

Comment: I have no idea but it is a possibility.All the windows look legit.When I try to open the defender it sais that my group has deactivated the use of Windows defender and if i am using other type of protection it will deactivate(i already knew this.I have no other protection)I didn´t want to use other protection the defender seemed to be enough for what i do.Any suggestions how to fix it ?

Comment: Read this question first: [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit).